# Why do GET requests not inherit the URL and use / absolute root instead

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, get

I wrote my own DNS server and I am resolving the address foo.bar to 127.0.0.1. In this same file I am also running an HTTP server using the BaseHTTPServer from python with a custom request handler. The current get request made from a browser correctly resolves the address to the local host and loads the index.html as it should. What confuses me is the fact that the GET request only shows:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2016 16:56:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Which according to rfc2616-sec5:

```
the absolute path cannot be empty; if none is present in the original URI, it MUST be given as "/" (the server root).
```

Which means at some point foo.bar is getting reduced to / even if I type http://foo.bar or http://www.foo.bar.

How do I pass the full URL to the GET request? I would also like to know why it is assuming that the link is not an absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method only gives the path and query string of the URL. If you want the host specified then you must get it from the `Host` header if available.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anywhere I can read further on this behavior?